# Mix order of answers in quiz Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Is it possible to mix order of answers in Vue.js? Now it is set up that first answer is correct and 2 wrong answers are second and third. Any solutions?

HTML:

```html
<input placeholder="Question..." v-model="questionIn" type="text" />
<br />
<input placeholder="Right Answer..." v-model="answercorrectIn" type="text" />
<br />
<input placeholder="Bad Answer..." v-model="answerfalse1In" type="text" />
<br />
<input placeholder="Bad Answer..." v-model="answerfalse2In" type="text" />
<br />
```

And here is JS Vue:

```js
    addQuestion()
        {
            if ((this.questionIn != "") && (this.answercorrectIn != "") && (this.answerfalse1In != "") && (this.answerfalse2In != ""))
            {
                this.questions.push(
                {
                    question: this.questionIn,
                    answers:
                    [
                        { id: 0, answer: this.answercorrectIn, correct: false },
                        { id: 1, answer: this.answerfalse1In, correct: false },
                        { id: 2, answer: this.answerfalse2In, correct: false }
                    ],
                    correct: [0],
                    false: [1, 2],
```

Answer (score 0):

See this ["shuffle answers"](https://youtu.be/4deVCNJq3qc?t=5025) part in a very good vue.js tutorial, she is implementing exactly what you need, using the [lodash shuffle function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle).

You can see there a full implementation to such feature with all the cases you should handle.

Answer (score 0):

You could [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/6277151) the answers in `addQuestion()`:

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    const temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
  }
}

export default {
  methods: {
    addQuestion() {
      if (/* ok to add */) {
        this.questions.push({
          question: this.questionIn,
          answers: shuffleArray([
            { id: 0, answer: this.answercorrectIn, correct: false },
            { id: 1, answer: this.answerfalse1In, correct: false },
            { id: 2, answer: this.answerfalse2In, correct: false }
          ]),
          correct: [0],
          false: [1, 2],
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-shuffle-answer-array-in-vue)